# Display taxonomies and use a thumbnail of an assigned post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I have a hierarchical taxonomy, example:

- Country

  - City

On the child term pages I want to list the siblings with a thumbnail. Out of the box taxonomies don't support thumbnails so I want to get the thumbnail of one of the custom posts assigned to the the term. What's the best way to make this possible?

```
$qobject = get_queried_object();

if(!empty($qobject->term_id)){

  // get current term
  $thiscat = get_term( get_queried_object() , 'vacations-areas' );
  $parent_name = get_term( $thiscat->parent )->name;

  // get childs terms
  $subcategories = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'vacations-areas',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'exclude' => $thiscat->term_id,
    'parent' => get_queried_object_id()
  ));

  // if no childs get siblings
  if(empty($subcategories) && $thiscat->parent != 0) {
    $subcategories = get_terms(array(
      'taxonomy' => 'vacations-areas',
      'hide_empty' => false,
      'exclude' => $thiscat->term_id,
      'parent' => $thiscat->parent
    ));
  } 

  if(!empty($subcategories)) {  ?>

    foreach($subcategories as $subcat) 

      echo $subcat->name;

      //
      // get the wp_get_attachment_image(  );
      //

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you’d have to start by actually fetching a post that is in that category then …

Comment: _“Out of the box taxonomies don't support thumbnails”_ - out of the box they might not, but it would be pretty easy to add that using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for example.

Comment: I know it's simple with ACF, but in this case I need to get a thumbnail from the first post.

Comment: Well, okay, do that then … where is your attempt?